# What is the use of the .p12 file in Xcode 8? Is distribution signing different from automatic signing?

Tags: ios, xcode

I am trying to sign my Xcode project using the following command:

```
xcrun -sdk iphoneos PackageApplication #project path -o outputpath.ipa -sign="name of sign" -embed="mobileprovision"
```

When I enter this command it returns the current directory I am in without any errors, but does not generate a IPA file, but if I remove the following from the command:

```
 xcrun -sdk iphoneos PackageApplication #project path -o outputpath.ipa
```

I do get a IPA file, but it does not seem to be signed. I have a .p12 file and .mobileprovision file, but don't know how to proceed. I am currently using Xcode version 7.3.1, but would also like to know how to do this with Xcode 8.

Comment: Please explain what is the output you are aiming for and if there are any restrictions (e.g. I have the use command line)

Comment: In short please tell me how i create ipa by passing .mobileprovision file and distribution certificate

Comment: There are numerous ways of doing that, why you can't using Xcode? are you trying to build a script or you can use a different tool to sign the app?

Comment: can you please tell me a one way to do that with xcodebuild , no i am not making any scripts

Answer (score 0):

There are few ways of doing that but since you are not trying to build a script the easiest way is using [iReSign](https://github.com/maciekish/iReSign) tool.

This tool input is ipa/xarchive file, p.12 file and a certificate (that you choose from your keychain).

You can also change the Bundle ID and the entitlements file of the ipa.
its open source and I've been using it for a while.

If you can't use this tool and use the command line `xcodebuild`:

Archive your app:

```
xcodebuild -scheme <scheme name> archive
```

now you have a `xarchive` file, export the app from the archive to ipa file:

```
xcodebuild -exportArchive -exportOptionsPlist "<pathToOptions>" -archivePath "<pathToArchive>"  -exportPath "<pathToOutput>"
```

You need to create option plist file and you can see the option available [here](https://gist.github.com/phatblat/0dd175b406cf2f3fbfc9)

Here is an example of an options file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
        <key>teamID</key>
        <string>MYTEAMID123</string>
        <key>method</key>
        <string>app-store</string>
        <key>uploadSymbols</key>
        <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Note: you can always use the help menu: `xcodebuild -h`

Note 2: you can setup your certificate and developer team in Xcode (need to be done once)

Comment: well i want commands so i can add them into my nodejs app , i am not create any shell script but a nodejs app

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: ok i will  trye  but what will come  in  -exportProvisioningProfile "My App Provisioning profile" , ?? filepath of .mobileprovision profile , name  of file what ???

Comment: Path to the file (you can download it from Apple developer portal)

Comment: hi i try  first i create archive then i try to export archive with follwing command   but i get error i past command with complete error  in the command line in second comment

Comment: xcodebuild -exportArchive -exportFormat ipa -archivePath "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/xcrpro/platforms/ios/myapp.xcarchive" -exportPath "myApp.ipa" -exportProvisioningProfile "/Users/fahimsaqib/Downloads/myapptest.mobileprovision"
--- xcodebuild: WARNING: -exportArchive without -exportOptionsPlist is deprecated
1.2.840.113635.100.1.61
1.2.840.113635.100.1.61
error: no provisioning profile matches '/Users/fahimsaqib/Downloads/myapptest.mobileprovision'
** EXPORT FAILED **

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: ok i will try and let u know , one last question can i disable automatic signing from command line using xcodebuild ??

Comment: you have to sign... there are ways to prevent signing but they are not straight forward...